# Module function in cython gets extra check that a static method doesn't

Tags: python, performance, arguments, cython

I have the following class static method and method user:

```py
@cython.cclass
class TestClass:

    @staticmethod
    @cython.cfunc
    def func(v: float) -> float:
        return v + 1.0

    def test_call(self):
        res = TestClass.func(2)
        return res
```

The line `res = TestClass.func(2)` shows as white in the annnotated version (as expected) and gets translated to C as

```
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_8crujisim_11cythontests_9TestClass_func(2.0); if (unlikely(PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 521, __pyx_L1_error)__pyx_v_res = __pyx_t_1;
```

But if I now take that static method out of the class and turn it into a function, as in

```py
@cython.cfunc
def func(v: float) -> float:
    return v + 1.0

@cython.cclass
class TestClass:

    def test_call(self):
        res = func(2)
        return res
```

Then the `res = func(2)` line is now yellow, and the C translation shows an additional test

```
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_8crujisim_11cythontests_func(2.0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_1 == ((double)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 521, __pyx_L1_error)__pyx_v_res = __pyx_t_1;
```

I am forced to get the method out of the class because of this behaviour I reported, which I believe is a bug https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/5159 . But the method call is inside a tight loop in the critical path and there is a noticeable performance loss.

Is it perhaps an argument overflow check? Can it be disabled? Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: The module-level version of actually generating better (i.e. faster) code because it's only calling the expensive `PyErr_Occurred` after checking for a special sentinel value. But they probably should generate the same code. Dunno why you've tagged this with "integer-overflow" though

Comment: Or at least it should be faster... It may be based on poor assumptions but it's certainly intended as an optimisation

Comment: OK, I've removed the integer-overflow tag. So my C is rusty and I misinterpreted the -1 check. Thanks for pointing that out. I still don't understand why the C code is not the same for both cases and why the second 'faster' one with the sentinel check is marked yellow in the annotated version. Is there any way to skip the checks altogether? The worst that could happen here anyways is an overflow, and it shouldn't happen in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `cdef`/`cfunc` function unable to raise an exception using `@cython.exceptval(check=False)` (or `cdef float func() noexcept` in the non-pure-Python syntax). See [the documentation for full details about exceptions](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values). If you do this it won't be checked.

Cython 3 has changed the default behaviour from "`cdef` functions swallow exceptions" to "`cdef` functions can raise exceptions", but it's possible to pick either.

---

The difference you see between `staticmethod` and a module-level function is probably a minor bug - there's no reason for them to behave differently.

However, I'd actually expect the extra check to be an optimization in the non-error case: `PyErr_Occurred()` is expected to be expensive, so using `-1` as a sentinal value to indicate that an error might have happened avoids it most of the time. I haven't measured it in your exact case though - it's probably a balance between skipping expensive checks vs greater code size.

The annotated HTML highlighting is pretty crude so is almost working on the basis that "more text == slower" which isn't quite right here. So don't take it *too* seriously.